# Log shipping restore delay of a minute between iterations

Tags: sql-server-2012, log-shipping

[image: Clip from errorlog]

On a test database running Log Shipping jobs the initial Restores to catch up performed the first time I run the Restore job seem to have a 1 minute or so Wait time built in.  I would have expected Log Shipping to Restore those backups in succession at maximum speed.  Each Restore is taking under a second to complete (TRNs are approx 50K each).  But the delay between each file where it Xlocks the DB again is 64 - 68 seconds but not a fixed amount.
Switching to No recovery has not changed a thing.
Thanks in advance for your help

...Ray

Comment: Do you have `delay restoring backups` to 1 min ?

Comment: I do not have any delay set.  If you look at the log, its also possible that the minute is spent trying to get Exclusive lock on the database (strange as it's in No Recovery mode).  The recovery job schedule is set for every minute but that is not applicable here since I am running it manually one-time and its applying all missing TRNs since the Seed Backup.  But it's taking over a minute per to do it.

Comment: interesting problem .. Is the msdb logshipping tables are having lots of records. Also, sql agent related tables having unusual amount of rows ? There is something usual going on. Try running sp_whoisactive while the restore is running.